# How to find strings which are thousands digits and remove comma in them?

Tags: python, csv

Here is the simple example of csv file:

```
ID, Name, p1, p2, p3, p4
3003,健和興,38.75,38.95,38.00,38.35
3005,神基,38.20,39.20,38.00,39.15
3008,大立光,"3,805.00","3,810.00","3,780.00","3,795.00"
3010,華立,45.90,46.00,45.80,45.85
3011,今皓,7.40,7.57,7.24,7.46
```

I want to change the data in row 3,

```
3008,大立光,"3,805.00","3,810.00","3,780.00","3,795.00"
```

become like this:

```
3008,大立光,3805.00,3810.00,3780.00,3795.00
```

and the csv file is like this:

```
ID, Name, p1, p2, p3, p4
3003,健和興,38.75,38.95,38.00,38.35
3005,神基,38.20,39.20,38.00,39.15
3008,大立光,3805.00,3810.00,3780.00,3795.00
3010,華立,45.90,46.00,45.80,45.85
3011,今皓,7.40,7.57,7.24,7.46
```

Because the original csv file has hundreds of rows, and I am not sure the thousands digits always appear in the same row, and hope the data can be convert to float. I don't know how to write the code in python?

Very much thanks for any help!

I tried to write code like below, but not work out:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv

with open('output_fixx_t.csv', 'r', newline = '') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    fixed = []
    for rows in reader:
       for field in rows:
         try:
            x = float(field)
            field.replace(",", "")
         except ValueError:
            pass
         fixed.append(field)
    with open('output_fixxx.csv', 'w', newline = '') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerow(fixed)
```

Comment: I would use the `csv` module to read the file.  It will parse the rows into lists, and will strip the quotes (which are only present because of the embedded commas).  You can then strip the commas from each cell of each row, then use the appropriate `csv` method to write the resulting csv file back out.

Answer (score 0):

If your file comes in all the same pattern as you have mentioned in your question, you can simply read your CSV as String and do your substitution or replacement using following regular expression. check these for more info [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) and [regular expression in python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

```
import re
re.sub(r'\"(\d+)\,(\d+\.\d+)\"', "\g<1>\g<2>", str)
```

I already tested the above pattern in code online using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com), just choose python, put your file content and put your pattern `\"(\d+)\,(\d+\.\d+)\"` and make sure you turn on regex flag `"/general"`

If you still have any problem, please leave a comment.

Comment: `'3008,\xe5\xa4\xa7\xe7\xab\x8b\xe5\x85\x89,$1$2,$1$2,$1$2,$1$2'`
This is what my output is. I think there is something missing

Comment: would you please share your regex code snippet now here in a comment

Comment: Can you try to use \1 instead of $1

Comment: `re.sub(r'\"(\d+)\,(\d+\.\d+)\"', "\1\2", s)` gives 
`'3008,\xe5\xa4\xa7\xe7\xab\x8b\xe5\x85\x89,\x01\x02,\x01\x02,\x01\x02,\x01\x02'`
but making it 
`re.sub(r'\"(\d+)\,(\d+\.\d+)\"', "\g<1>\g<2>", s)` gives 
`'3008,\xe5\xa4\xa7\xe7\xab\x8b\xe5\x85\x89,3805.00,3810.00,3780.00,3795.00'`. For some reason it only the long form of mentioning groups work in my system.

Comment: So is it working for you now!! I already updated my answer in include \g, if so please mark as a correct answer otherwise please let me know the exact problem you might have

Comment: I did not ask the question. I was merely interested in the answer :)

Comment: I write the code like this:

    `a = [3008,大立光,"3,805.00","3,810.00","3,780.00","3,795.00"]`
    `re.sub(r'\"(\d+)\,(\d+\.\d+)\"', "$1$2", a)`

come out error message:

    `NameError: name '大立光' is not defined`